# How to cut tube in half in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a SCNTube and wanted to see if there is a way to cut the tube in half? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use custom geometry, or your favorite 3D editing tool (Maya, SketchUp, Blender, Cheetah3D).

You could in theory extract and cut up the geometry created by the `SCNTube`, but that format is undocumented (therefore subject to change), and would be a lot of work.